# Php blank lines

Tags: php

```
$i=0;
while($i<=8){
    $id=$recenti['games'][0]['fellowPlayers'][$i]['summonerId'];
    $teamid=$recenti['games'][0]['fellowPlayers'][$i]['teamId'];
    $altri = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://euw.api.pvp.net/api/lol/euw/v1.4/summoner/'.$id.'?api_key=my_api_key'), true);  
    $nome=$altri[$id]['name'];
    if ($teamid===200){
        echo '<div style="float:right">',$nome,'</div><br>';      
    }
    else{
       echo '<div style="float:left">',$nome,'</div><br>';
    }
    $i++;     
}
```

I used PHP with JSON to retrieve data of my last match and have the names of the players with riot API. In HTML this results me full of blank spaces.

**Example:**

```
Test1
                                                                       Test2
Test3
                                                                       Test4
Test5
Test6
                                                                       Test7
                                                                       Test8
Test9
```

I would like to remove the blank lines, how can I?

Comment: Do you mean the name at right? you have the float to right which align to right

Comment: yes but i need to remove the blank line, like "Test4" and "Test7", i want the  remove the 2 blank lines between

Comment: the problem is that those rows are filled by Test5 and Test6, you have to change your css approach

Comment: why not use a html table?

Comment: This question is nothing to do with PHP. Remove the PHP code, and instead include your HTML. Don't forget to change tags on the question as well!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You a proposal, try:

```
    $i=0;
    $left = array();
    $right = array();
    while($i<=8){
        $id=$recenti['games'][0]['fellowPlayers'][$i]['summonerId'];
        $teamid=$recenti['games'][0]['fellowPlayers'][$i]['teamId'];
        $altri = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://euw.api.pvp.net/api/lol/euw/v1.4/summoner/'.$id.'?api_key=my_api_key'), true);
        $nome=$altri[$id]['name'];
        if ($teamid===200){
            array_push(right, $nome);
            echo '<div style="float:right">',$nome,'</div><br>';
        }
        else{
            array_push($left, $nome);

            echo '<div style="float:left">',$nome,'</div><br>';
        }
        $i++;
    }

    echo '<div style="float:left">';
    foreach (left as $nome) {
        echo $nome.'<br />';
    }
    echo '</div>';

    echo '<div style="float:right">';
    foreach ($right as $nome) {
        echo $nome.'<br />';
    }
    echo '</div>';
```

Basically push the names in two array for left and righ columns.